# String to Object reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, object

I'm doing a migration where some data from columns that are being dropped needs to be converted into a different form.  There is no guarantee that all of the data will be available at the time of the migration, so I need to convert the data during the seed.

I'm saving the object and data using

```
Object.find_each do |object|
  file_out.puts(object)
  file_out.puts(object.attribute)
```

However, when reading this object reference back in later, using

```
object = file_in.gets
```

I get the error

```
undefined method 'update_attributes' for `#<Object:0xe1b6f44>:String`
```

How can I convert that string back into the actual Object Reference.  Due to the database using schema, no database columns are guaranteed unique.

Answer (score 1):

You don't; you'd serialize the object, not just dump out its `to_s` string representation.

When you read it back in you'd deserialize it.

That said, it seems like it'd be easier to do each "thing" all at once rather than relying on something like this, since serializing it would also serialize its ID, and if it no longer exists with that ID (assuming it's a DB object), you're hosed unless you explicitly handle that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant do each "thing" all at once because some information will actually come from a later migration (I know its a pain, but I cant get around it).  Since this is something happening during a migration and immediate seed, the object will still exist with same ID

Comment: I just read about serialize, but it seems that would fail.  The default object in each schema could have all 50 fields the same....

Comment: @user3027875: Serialization is a process for flattening an object into some format that can be stored (such as on a disk) or transferred (over a network connection for example), the ActiveRecord `serialize` method doesn't have much to do with serialization in general. You need to serialize your objects to JSON, YAML, or some other format rather than use AR's `serialize`.